# c++ overloading [] to print nth item of linked list

Tags: c++, list, overloading, operator-keyword

I have an assignment which involves different linked list operations. One of them involves overloading the square bracket operator to be able to print the ith element of the linked list. I have everything else done but I am really lost on this. This is what I am working with. The list class is as follows:

```
class List {
public:
// Creates a default empty list
List();

// Simple destructor
~List();

// Insert "data" at the very end of the list
void AddToFront(int data);

// Remove and return the first data item from the list.
int deleteFront();

// Prints the list
void Print() ;

// Returns the size of the list
unsigned int Size() const;


//overloaded assignment operator
Node operator[](unsigned int i) ;



private:

Node *m_head;

};
```

Also, here is my node class:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    ~Node();
    Node(int data);

    int m_data;
    Node *m_next;
};
```

Any help on the overloading [] operator would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would you write a normal function to return the i'th node?

Answer (score 2):

```
Node* operator [] (int value) {
    Node *temp = this->m_head;
    for(int i = 0; i < value && temp!=NULL; i++) {
        temp = temp->m_next;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I assume that you want to return the node corresponding to the `value` specified, in the square brackets. You overload any operator using the `operator` keyword followed by the operator, and then the parameters passed.

For more info check this :: [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

**EDIT ::**

As pointed by erip and Lajos there should be a way, in case the `(value > size_of_list)`, in that case, a possible solution would be throw an exception, which you can later catch in your program to show that `value` was out of bound. Or considering the current implementation, if `value > size_of_list` in that case `temp` would become `NULL`, so during your execution you can check if value of `Node *` returned is `NULL` or not.

A further more optimized way would be to keep a variable `size_of_list` in the class `List`, and then we can simply add an `if` condition to the function like this ::

```
if(value >= size_of_list) // equal to sign is put, considering your `size_of_list` starts from 1
    return NULL;
```

This, would be more optimized in case of large Lists, which would avoid wasteful execution of the `for` loop!

Comment: It would make more sense to return `m_data` for the ith `Node`, but that doesn't change much. Nice answer.

Comment: You should probably do something else besides `temp!=NULL`, too. For example, `if(size_of_list < value) /* throw exception */`

Comment: @erip True, but I don't think the OP wants to keep an extra variable in the `list` class, moreover I intended to check what I return, if I return `NULL` from the function that would mean `size_of_list < value` I have always had more love for `if else` than exception :P

Comment: If the element is not found, then you might consider throwing an exception. Also, you might consider using a currentElement Node member for List along with a currentIndex, because then, by any chance currentIndex <= value, you can use a shortcut. This would be useful for very long lists.

Comment: @user007 OP has a `Size` method, implying he has a size attribute in the `List` class. Your current implementation returns the last element if `size < value`, so if you have list [1, 2, 3] and `value` is 100, you return the `3`, which is unexpected.

Comment: Unless OP calculates the size of the list every time `Size` is called. That wouldn't be good.

Comment: @erip It won't return the last element, I checking for `temp` and not `temp->next`, so in case value `val > size` I return `NULL` I don't understand where it is wrong.